# Cannot get state store wf-spec-name because no such store is registered in the topology

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple KafkaStreams topology which takes in a topic `'foo'` where each record is a JSON blob (which I Serde into a `TaskDefSchema`), keyed by some guid. I wish to construct two queryable `GlobalKTable`'s, such that there are two `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, FooThing>`'s:

1. One keyed by the guid (i.e. the input topic `foo` unchanged).
2. One keyed by the `TaskDefSchema.name` field in the JSON blob.

As follows is my code:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, TaskDefSchema> taskDefEvents = builder.stream(
            config.getTaskDefTopic(), // 'foo' in the question above
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new TaskDefSerdes())
        );

        KStream<String, TaskDefSchema> taskDefEventsNameKeyed = taskDefEvents.selectKey(
            ((k, v) -> v.name)
        );
        String intermediateTopicByName = config.getTaskDefTopic() + "__intermediate_name";
        String intermediateTopicByGuid = config.getTaskDefTopic() + "__intermediate_guid";

        taskDefEventsNameKeyed.to(intermediateTopicByName);
        taskDefEvents.to(intermediateTopicByGuid);

        this.taskDefNameTable = builder.globalTable(
            intermediateTopicByName,
            Materialized.<String, TaskDefSchema, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                as("wf-spec-name")
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(new TaskDefSerdes())
        );

        this.taskDefGuidTable = builder.globalTable(
            intermediateTopicByGuid,
            Materialized.<String, TaskDefSchema, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                as("wf-spec-guid")
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(new TaskDefSerdes())
        );

        return builder.build();
```

When I try to query the stores as follows:

```
        kafkaStreams.store(
            StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(
                "wf-spec-guid",
                QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()
            )
        );
```

the function call returns a KeyValueStore that works as expected. *Note: The block above corresponds to the second GlobalTable—the taskDefGuidTable.*

However, when I make the following call to retrieve the **re-keyed** globalTable (i.e. taskDefGuidTable), I get an error:

```
        kafkaStreams.store(
            StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(
                "wf-spec-name", // this is the line that's different (:
                QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()
            )
        );


/* *********************** */


org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.UnknownStateStoreException: Cannot get state store wf-spec-name because no such store is registered in the topology.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well...oops. The `kafkaStreams` object I was querying turned out to be the wrong one (I have multiple `KafkaStreams` going on in my code..oops).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).